# How to draw transparent image in c#

Tags: c#, listbox, transparent

I made a ListBox.

There are image and Text in ListBox Like picture.

[image]

And i want to draw transparent Image on listbox When mousemove.

```
private void ListBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    int iWidth = image.Width;
    int iHeight = image.Height;

    ImageAttributes attr = new ImageAttributes();

    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.Matrix33 = 0.8f;
    attr.SetColorMatrix(matrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0 iWidth, iHeight), 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);
}
```

This is my code.

But I have a problem.

Although I input the same value of transparency, Transparency of each image is different..

How can I solve it ??

++ Add Code

I use Scrollbar.

```
int LocationY = ListBox.PreferredHeight / ListBox.Items.Count * (Index/*ListBox index*/ - ListBox.TopIndex);
if ((LocationY + image.Height) > Listbox.Height)
       LocationY = ListBox.Height - image.Height;

e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, LocationY, iWidth, iHeight), 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);
```

Comment: _I edited my content. can you check my code ?_ - I'll try. note that I had coded for ListView! But could you please check the code? It doesn't compile as it is!

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much~

Comment: Also: What is it about the MouseMove you mention? Please edit the question for more clarity! - And: Yu need to explain exactly what you want to achieve. Btw: For Listboxes the same applies: The DrawItem is called for each item separately durting a refresh and then again when selecting items. So it must refer to the ITems's bounds!!

Comment: I try to draw enlarge and Transparent Image when mousemove. The Image is image in ListBox Like picture. I want to paint on start point of each listbox item and the problem is mentioned above.

Comment: _when mousemove_ What does this mean? Show the code for the MouseMove! Do you want one image per item or one image for the whole listbox? note that you can only draw the items, not the whole listbox!

Comment: sorry. mousemove is mouseover.. and I want to draw one image per item.

Comment: so what is the code for the moveover? Here is a quick fix you may want to try Insert this `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);` before the DrawImage!

Comment: mouseover is just getting point code.(Point point = ListBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            int index = ListBox.IndexFromPoint(point);)  i inserted  that code and  all listbox was painted white.So I use Brushes.Transparent. But The problem is still....

Comment: I think e.BackColor is problem. But BackColor is readonly. so I can't change backcolor.

Comment: e.BackColor is the ListBox's BackColor. I don't see where you use it. What do you do with the point?

Answer (score 0):

When ownerdrawing a `ListBox` it is important to understand how the `DrawItem` event is called.

It will be called on **several** occasions, always referring only to the `Item` it was called for.

But for better performance **not all** occasions will make the `ListBox` draw **all** its items!

The area you are meant to draw on is the `e.Bounds` rectangle.

You can still draw over the whole `ListBox` but as the event usually is called several times in a row you may run into some issues. One such issue is with **transparent** drawings, as these will **stack** and become less and less transparent!

Let's look a few cases:

- During a `Refresh` all visible Items will be drawn
- When **selecting** an `Item` the **selected** item **and** also **all previously selected** items will be drawn

So, after the initial display each item will have been drawn **once** but after selecting `item3` and then `item1` the first three items will all have been drawn different times: `item1`: 2x, `item2`:1x and `item3`: 3x.

The workaound will usually be to create a clean slate before drawing an item, maybe like this:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
```

This however will not go well with anything you draw across the item bounds!

Any image you draw on an `Item` should respect the bounds. You can either squeeze an image into the item's bounds:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, e.Bounds, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);
```

Or you can draw just a slice of a larger image, maybe like this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, e.Bounds, 
                            0, e.Index * e.Bounds.Height, iWidth, e.Bounds.Height, 
                            GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);
```

Comment: I see. But I change the image of location. so I can't use e.Bounds.

Comment: But you will need to. What exactly do you mean by 'changing the Image location'? - Note that the DrawItem method will be called __for each__ Item!!